# Caching a value to be used within an Angular 2 view?

Tags: angular

I use a long expression twice within a single element in an Angular 2 view:

```
<a *ngIf="row.getEmployer()[i]!.getProfileLink()"
   class="x-view-link"
   href="{{ row.getEmployer().getEmployee()[i]!.getProfileLink() }}">
  xv
</a>
```

Could I somehow store `row.getEmployer().getEmployee()[i]!.getProfileLink()` inside a variable (called say `link`, ie `let link = row.getEmployer().getEmployee()[i]!.getProfileLink()`) within the view and then reuse that variable?

Comment: Can you add the whole snippet of ngFor so that it would be easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can because you use a condition.

Try that :

```
<a *ngIf="row.getEmployer()[i]!.getProfileLink() as link"
```

Link will now contain the result of your variable.

Comment: ([more information in the documentation here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#storing-conditional-result-in-a-variable))

Comment: What about the scope of the link Variable?  *entire template*